# Unrecognized USB device on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have car diagnostic device ELM327 with usb port connection, but Mint can't recognize it.
Here is the list of devices from terminal:

```
~ $ lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 09da:000e A4 Tech Co., Ltd
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 7073:3037
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c215 Logitech, Inc. Extreme 3D Pro
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

That device is listed as "Bus 003 Device 003" and, as you can see, has no description.

Any suggestions? Does it have some further procedure to been recognized by auto-data software? Cant find this solved problem googleing.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `udev` or `hald`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found other people who had the same problem as you by googling: [Here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=98396&p=560933) and [Here (in Polish)](http://ubuntu.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?f=140&t=154218).

"It says FTDI, manufacturer of the device, has a Linux driver to be able to use this interface as a serial port."

Knowing that you might try [the FTDI site](http://www.ftdichip.com/FTDrivers.htm). EDIT: The FTDI site says that it is supported natively in kernel 2.6.31 and later. See also [the FTDI driver sourceforge project](http://ftdi-usb-sio.sourceforge.net/).

Note that none of this tells you what protocol you speak to it.

Comment: Thank you. This sources should be more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

lsusb merely translates the IDs (provided by the device) into text strings, using `/usr/share/usb.ids`. That does not say anything about the (un)availability of a driver.